# Getting error after updating image in Sql server 2008 database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms-designer, image-conversion

I am developing a winform application in VS 2010 C#.
I have developed a form to insert and update the user details in this.

My Update user form is as below image

![Update User Screen][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZaAJ.png

And coding to update is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace SampleApplication
{
public partial class UserUpdate : Form
{
    public UserUpdate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=sa; password=123;initial     catalog=Inventory;data source=Aniket-PC");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    MemoryStream ms;
    byte[] photo_array;
    DataSet ds;
    int rno = 0;
    string str;
    private void nameTxt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (nameTxt.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            namewarning.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            namewarning.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contTxt.MaxLength = 10;
        retriveData();
        retriveImg();
    }
    void retriveImg()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Logo from Register where UserName='" + uNameTxt.Text + "'", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet("MyImage");
        da.Fill(ds, "MyImage");
        DataRow myRow;
        myRow = ds.Tables["MyImage"].Rows[0];
        photo_array = (byte[])myRow["Logo"];
        ms = new MemoryStream(photo_array);
        profPic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        con.Close();
    }

    void retriveData()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Register where UserName='"+uNameTxt.Text+"'",con);
        SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read())
        {
            nameTxt.Text = (read["Name"].ToString());
            passTxt.Text = (read["Password"].ToString());
            conPassTxt.Text = (read["Password"].ToString());
            emailTxt.Text = (read["EmailId"].ToString());
            addTxt.Text = (read["Address"].ToString());
            contTxt.Text = (read["ContactNo"].ToString());
            DORTxt.Text = (read["DOR"].ToString());
            validity.Text = "Account Valid till "+(read["Validity"].ToString());
        }
        read.Close();
        con.Close();            
    }

    private void AttachBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open  image by OpenFiledialog and show it in PicturBox.
        try
        {
            //filter only image format files.
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "jpeg|*.jpg|bmp|*.bmp|all files|*.*";
            DialogResult res = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (res == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image img = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                //inserting image in PicturBox
                profPic.Image = img.GetThumbnailImage(127, 128, null, new IntPtr());
                openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot upload image");
        }
    }
    private void UpdateBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string DOM = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
        if (namewarning.Visible == true || picError.Visible == true || PassError.Visible == true || emailwarningImg.Visible == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please correct the marked fields");
        }
        else
        {
            //cmd = new SqlCommand("update Register set (Name,Password,EmailId,Address,ContactNo,Logo,DOM) values('" + nameTxt.Text.Trim() + "','" + passTxt.Text.Trim() + "','" + emailTxt.Text.Trim() + "','" + addTxt.Text.Trim() + "','" + contTxt.Text.Trim() + "',@Logo,'"  + DOM+ "')", con);
            str = string.Format("update Register set Name='{0}', Password='{1}',EmailID='{2}',Address='{3}',ContactNo='{4}',Logo='{5}',DOU='{6}' where UserName='{7}'", nameTxt.Text.Trim(), passTxt.Text.Trim(), emailTxt.Text.Trim(),addTxt.Text.Trim(), contTxt.Text.Trim(), @"Logo" ,DOM,uNameTxt.Text);
            con_photo();
            //con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            int count= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (count > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Sucsess");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("need to work");
        }
    }
    void con_photo()
    {
        if (profPic.Image != null)
        {
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            profPic.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] photo_array = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(photo_array, 0, photo_array.Length);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Logo", photo_array);
        }
    }
```

when i run the application it executes very well and shows me success message but when i again try to view the update user form it shows below screenshot error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z1Rx.png

at retriveImg ()

Please help me with resolution for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the image bytes to the `UPDATE` command, but a string containing the word `Logo`.

Also: *PLEASE* avoid creating SQL commands using string concatenation or `String.Format`. Use parameterized queries instead!

---

Also: Do not use an `NVARCHAR` field to store the image bytes (unless you create a BASE64 string from them first), but use a `VARBINARY` or `IMAGE` column instead.

---

The problem is in the following line:

```
str = string.Format("update Register set ... ,Logo='{5}' ...", ..., @"Logo", ...);
```

As you can see, you're formatting a string, but you don't insert the bytes from the image, but the word "Logo".

Assuming the column `Logo` was of type `IMAGE` or `VARBINARY`, I would write something like this:

```
byte[] photo_array = null;

if (profPic.Image != null)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    profPic.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    photo_array = ms.GetBuffer();
}

if (photo_array != null)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Register SET Logo=@logo", connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logo", imageBytes);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help here but could you explain me this little bit more as i am not full aware of these all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I'll try to do this

```
photo_array = (byte[])myRow["Logo"];
if photo_array.length.trim()>0
{
    ms = new MemoryStream(photo_array);  
    profPic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

}
con.Close();
```

This error may come when the lenght of the string is 0

Another thing is that you're not saving the image in the database

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can not store a byte array into a `NVARCHAR` field like he wants to.

Comment: One solution using NVARCHAR maybe to trim the white spaces in the Photo_Array variable? I've modified the code the reflect what I'm saying here

Comment: Thank you @thorsten dittmar for your suggestions here. I am trying to fix it as you explained but no success yet.could you please help me little bit more with code sample for how to update my user details with user image. Your help is most appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

//C#  Code

SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("select ImageValue    from  table where ID=1", ObjCon);
            ObjCon.Open();

```
        byte[] barrImg = (byte[])cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();
        ObjCon.Close();
         string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Temp\\1.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
        fs.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
```

// 1.txt file will be created in c:\temp folder